# setAttribute background-image can't be changed. Stuck at default value

Tags: javascript, css, dom, slideshow, transition

```js
function showHome() {
  removeSlideShow();
  var homeHeader = document.createElement("div");
  homeHeader.setAttribute("id", "homeHeader");
  document.getElementById("window").insertBefore(homeHeader, document.getElementById("content"));
  var slideShowDiv = document.createElement("div");
  var images = ["slideShow/slideShow-1.jpg", "slideShow/slideShow-2.jpg", "slideShow/slideShow-3.jpg", "slideShow/slideShow-4.jpg", "slideShow/slideShow-5.jpg", "slideShow/slideShow-6.jpg", "slideShow/slideShow-7.jpg"];
  homeHeader.appendChild(slideShowDiv);
  startSlideShow(slideShowDiv, images);
  content.innerHTML = "";
}

function startSlideShow(element, images) {
  var iterator = 0;
  element.setAttribute("id", "slideShowDiv");
  element.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url(" + images[0] + ")");
  var startInterval = setInterval(function() {
    iterator++;
    if (iterator == images.length) iterator = 0;
    element.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url(" + images[iterator] + ")");
    element.style = "background-image: url(" + images[iterator] + ")";
    transition(element);
  }, 3000);
}

function removeSlideShow() {
  if (document.getElementById("homeHeader")) {
    document.getElementById("window").removeChild(document.getElementById("homeHeader"));
  }
}

function transition(element) {
  element.setAttribute("style", "opacity:0.01;");
  var i = 0;
  var set = setInterval(function() {
    i += 0.01;
    element.setAttribute("style", "opacity:" + i + ";");
  }, 4);
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(set);
    element.setAttribute("style", "opacity:1;");
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
div#homeHeader {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 900px;
  height: 280px;
  border: solid 2px #F00;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
div#slideShowDiv {
  background-image: url(slideShow/slideShow-1.jpg);
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 898px;
  height: 278px;
  border: solid 1px #FFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

What i want to do is change the background image every 3 seconds. The code work but it's not changing the image, stays at 'slideShow-1.jpg'. If i remove the transition(element); part, the image rotate just fine. What should i do to get it work? Im still beginner in Javascript, will learn jquery when i got better. Sorry for my grammar.

Comment: Add Html too in your snippet

Comment: Try once using Style backgroundImage Property i.e. `element.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + images[0] + "')";` You also need to __move `var images=[]` to global scope__

Comment: @Satpal — `images` is passed as a function argument, it doesn't need to be a global.

Comment: @Quentin, missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i remove the transition(element); part, the image rotate just fine.

The transition part sets a new value for the style attribute.

Setting a new value for the attribute replaces the old value.

You are removing the style for the background image. (So the one from the stylesheet is applied again instead).

> What should i do to get it work?

Don't use `setAttribute(..., ...)` to modify styles.

[Use `.style.cssPropertyName = ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) instead.